# show_chunks() does not show chunks when giving interval as arguement

Tags: postgresql, chunks, timescaledb

I created a hypertable `drt` with chunk size of 1 hour in my timescaleDB

```
| random | time                       |

| ------ | -------------------------- |

| 4      | 2021-10-20 12:34:08.070423 |

| 5      | 2021-10-20 12:58:00.568898 |
```

and when I ran

```
SELECT show_chunks('drt')
```

I got one chunk in the output but when I ran

```
SELECT show_chunks('drt', older_than => INTERVAL '2 hours')
```

I got no output. I can't understand why. The chunks are older than 2 hours.

```
select now() - interval '2 hours' ;
```

gives

```
2021-10-20 14:28:35.105981+00
```

UPDATE:
I ran

```
select show_chunks('drt', older_than=>interval 'N hours');
```

multiple times, chaning the value of N. Yesterday I was getting the output on N<=18. But today I am seeing the same chunk after setting the value of N<=11. This query should return all the chunks that were created before N hours. N should increase with time. Right? What am I missing here?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if maybe this is a timezone issue?
You can check the chunks directly in the `timescaledb_information.chunks` view.

Just see how many chunks it returns to you:

```sql
select * from timescaledb_information.chunks where hypertable_name = 'drt' and range_end < now() -  INTERVAL '1 hour' ;
```

Note that it's 15:37 to me (GMT-3) here but my server is outside:

```sql
select now() -  INTERVAL '1 hour';
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│           ?column?            │
├───────────────────────────────┤
│ 2021-10-20 17:36:48.833827+00 │
└───────────────────────────────┘
```

You can check the type of data you have:

```sql
select pg_typeof(now() -  INTERVAL '1 hour');
┌──────────────────────────┐
│        pg_typeof         │
├──────────────────────────┤
│ timestamp with time zone │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I don't have any view named `chunks` in my `timescaledb_information`. I'm on `v1.7.4`. And the query `select now() -  INTERVAL '1 hour';` would give the response in the server's timezone only. Right? So it shouldn't create any problem. The column's type is `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: As it's timescale 1.7.4 I'm not sure. I'm only following since 2.1. Please, consider updating your version to get more benefits from timescaledb! A lot of fixes and improvements are done since there.